# Security holes or vulnerabilities in ReactJS?

Tags: security, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out what kind of security issues could occur with ReactJS but I'm having trouble finding any. A quick Google search for Angular brings a few useful websites. Are they any for ReactJS or can someone explain it?

Comment: It's JavaScript and HTML. I'm not sure what noteworthy security issues you're expecting to find. It doesn't even have built-in Ajax. http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: Well if there aren't any noteworthy security issues, then I suppose I suppose I could go with the link you have. I just needed a general overview of possible concerns. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @WiredPrarie has pointed out React automatically [escapes for XSS](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks).

> If you want to display an HTML entity within dynamic content, you will run into double escaping issues as React escapes all the strings you are displaying in order to prevent a wide range of XSS attacks by default.

An example of a found recent vulnerability can be seen [here](http://danlec.com/blog/xss-via-a-spoofed-react-element), but has long since been fixed.

Also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158874/why-does-react-js-api-warn-against-inserting-raw-html) regarding insertion of raw html.

Be aware that using Isomorphic / Server Side Rendering can yield potential vulnerabilities, particularly in cases where initial state is embedded in a page to be served.  See this [link](https://medium.com/node-security/the-most-common-xss-vulnerability-in-react-js-applications-2bdffbcc1fa0).